# Is it possible to have 2 testclasses in one file in Unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
import ....

class Test1:

  @classmethod
  def setUpClass(self):
    ...

  def test_something(self):
    ...

  @classmethod
  def tearDownClass(self):
    ...

class Test2:

  @classmethod
  def setUpClass(self):
    ...

  def test_anotherthing(self):
    ...

  @classmethod
  def tearDownClass(self):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest2.main()
```

Comment: Yes, why  didn't you try it :) and by the way your class should inherit from `unittest.TestCase`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Why don't you give it a whirl?

Here's an example, where my test classes inherit from `unittest.TestCase` and the tests deliberately fail:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest

class TestAddition(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_addition(self):
        self.assertEquals(3, 1 + 1)

class TestSubtraction(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_subtraction(self):
        self.assertEquals(3, 1 - 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

% ./t.py 
FF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_addition (__main__.TestAddition)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 8, in test_addition
    self.assertEquals(3, 1 + 1)
AssertionError: 3 != 2

======================================================================
FAIL: test_subtraction (__main__.TestSubtraction)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 13, in test_subtraction
    self.assertEquals(3, 1 - 1)
AssertionError: 3 != 0

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's possible, just make sure they inherit from `unittest.TestCase`. Then, `unittest.main` will discover and run them.

You can also run just some of the tests in a file, by using the`unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase` or `unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromNames` methods.